# "Target class [App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference] does not exist.", - rebing graphl query - working for UserQuery, not UsersQuery with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, graphql-php

I am using https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel and getting the error when I run my UsersQuery

```
"Target class [App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference] does not exist."
```

Here is the top of the `WorkPreferenceType` class

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Types;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class WorkPreferenceType extends GraphQLType
{
```

The type is defined in the `graphql.php` file and the `GraphQL\Types` folder.

```
'work_preference'    => App\GraphQL\Types\WorkPreferenceType::class
```

The `UserType.php` references the `WorkPreferenceType` like so:

```
    'work_preferences' => [
        'type' => Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('work_preference')),
        'resolve' => function ($user) {
            $work_preferences = $user->work_preferences()->get();
            $updateWorkPreferences = new UpdateWorkPreferences;
            return $updateWorkPreferences->addWorkPreferencesTypeData($work_preferences);
        }
    ]
```

The UserQuery works with the WorkPreference type, however the UsersQuery that uses pagination does not work and throws the error.

I think it has something to do with the `getSelectFields` but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "debugMessage": "Target class [App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference] does not exist.",
            "message": "Internal server error",
            "extensions": {
                "category": "internal"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 2
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "users"
            ],
            "trace": [
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Container\/Container.php",
                    "line": 758,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container::build('App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php",
                    "line": 851,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container::resolve('App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference', array(0), true)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Container\/Container.php",
                    "line": 694,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application::resolve('App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference', array(0))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php",
                    "line": 836,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container::make('App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference', array(0))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/helpers.php",
                    "line": 119,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application::make('App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference', array(0))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/SelectFields.php",
                    "line": 112,
                    "function": "app('App\\GraphQL\\Types\\WorkPreference')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/SelectFields.php",
                    "line": 82,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields::getTableNameFromParentType(GraphQLType: WorkPreference)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/SelectFields.php",
                    "line": 210,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields::getSelectableFieldsAndRelations(array(1), array(3), GraphQLType: WorkPreference, null, false, instance of App\\User)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/SelectFields.php",
                    "line": 185,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields::handleFields(array(1), array(3), GraphQLType: User, array(2), array(0), instance of App\\User)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/SelectFields.php",
                    "line": 85,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields::handleFields(array(1), array(2), GraphQLType: userPagination, array(2), array(0), instance of App\\User)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/SelectFields.php",
                    "line": 53,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields::getSelectableFieldsAndRelations(array(1), array(2), GraphQLType: userPagination, null, true, instance of App\\User)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/Field.php",
                    "line": 253,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\SelectFields::__construct(GraphQLType: userPagination, array(1), instance of App\\User, array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/Field.php",
                    "line": 221,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Field::instanciateSelectFields(array(4), array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/app\/GraphQL\/Queries\/UsersQuery.php",
                    "line": 59,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Field::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\{closure}()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/Field.php",
                    "line": 237,
                    "call": "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\UsersQuery::resolve(null, array(1), instance of App\\User, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/Field.php",
                    "line": 150,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Field::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\{closure}(null, array(1), instance of App\\User, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 128,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Field::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\{closure}(array(4))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 103,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(4))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/Field.php",
                    "line": 149,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 623,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Field::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\{closure}(null, array(1), instance of App\\User, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 549,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveFieldValueOrError(instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\FieldDefinition, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\FieldNode, instance of Closure, null, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 1195,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveField(GraphQLType: Query, null, instance of ArrayObject(1), array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 264,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeFields(GraphQLType: Query, null, array(0), instance of ArrayObject(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 215,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeOperation(instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\OperationDefinitionNode, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/Executor.php",
                    "line": 156,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::doExecute()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 161,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\Executor::promiseToExecute(instance of GraphQL\\Executor\\Promise\\Adapter\\SyncPromiseAdapter, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of App\\User, null, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 93,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\GraphQL::promiseToExecute(instance of GraphQL\\Executor\\Promise\\Adapter\\SyncPromiseAdapter, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of App\\User, null, null, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/GraphqlExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 32,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\GraphQL::executeQuery(instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of App\\User, null, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\GraphqlExecutionMiddleware::handle('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, instance of App\\User, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::resolve(array(5), instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 33,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(5))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AddAuthUserContextValueMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 28,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\{closure}('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, instance of App\\User)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AddAuthUserContextValueMiddleware::handle('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, instance of App\\User, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::resolve(array(5), instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 33,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(5))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AutomaticPersistedQueriesMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 42,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\{closure}('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AutomaticPersistedQueriesMiddleware::handle('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::resolve(array(5), instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 33,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(5))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/ValidateOperationParamsMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 39,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\{closure}('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\ValidateOperationParamsMiddleware::handle('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::resolve(array(5), instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 103,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(5))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 113,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 157,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::thenReturn()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 140,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQL::executeViaMiddleware(array(4), 'v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 126,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQL::executeAndReturnResult('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQLController.php",
                    "line": 43,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQL::execute('v1', instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Helpers.php",
                    "line": 24,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQLController::Rebing\\GraphQL\\{closure}(instance of GraphQL\\Server\\OperationParams)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQLController.php",
                    "line": 39,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Helpers::applyEach(instance of Closure, instance of GraphQL\\Server\\OperationParams)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Controller.php",
                    "line": 54,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQLController::query(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Laragraph\\Utils\\RequestParser, instance of Illuminate\\Config\\Repository, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQL)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/ControllerDispatcher.php",
                    "line": 45,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller::callAction('query', array(4))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Route.php",
                    "line": 261,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher::dispatch(instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQLController, 'query')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Route.php",
                    "line": 205,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route::runController()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 721,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route::run()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 128,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Middleware\/ThrottleRequests.php",
                    "line": 127,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Middleware\/ThrottleRequests.php",
                    "line": 58,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests::handleRequest(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure, array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure, '100', '1')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Auth\/Middleware\/Authenticate.php",
                    "line": 44,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure, 'api')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 103,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 719,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 698,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::runRouteWithinStack(instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route, instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 662,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::runRoute(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 651,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::dispatchToRoute(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Kernel.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::dispatch(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 128,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/app\/Http\/Middleware\/Cors.php",
                    "line": 19,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\Cors::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/app\/Http\/Middleware\/IdentifyTenant.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\IdentifyTenant::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/TransformsRequest.php",
                    "line": 21,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/TransformsRequest.php",
                    "line": 21,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/TrimStrings.php",
                    "line": 40,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/ValidatePostSize.php",
                    "line": 27,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
                    "line": 86,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/fideloper\/proxy\/src\/TrustProxies.php",
                    "line": 57,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 103,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Kernel.php",
                    "line": 142,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Kernel.php",
                    "line": 111,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::sendRequestThroughRouter(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/public\/index.php",
                    "line": 54,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "users": null
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what is the literal `namespace` of `WorkPreference` file and the config, did you use `WorkPreference::class` and did `use App\GraphQL\Types\WorkPreference;` on top of the file? is the file literally inside a folder following this path (case sensitive): `PROJECT_ROOT/app/GraphQL/Types`?

Comment: @matiaslauriti i added those details to the question. Let me know if I am missing something or something is incorrect

Comment: Everything looks correct, except `repsolve` (`work_preferences -> repsolve`), is that a typo in the question or truly on the file?

Comment: ok cool, and yes that was a typo. I just corrected it. I just think it's strange that it works for the UserQuery but not UsersQuery. Is there something that I need to add to configure what the 'getSelectFields' should choose? Or could it be a config issue somewhere else?

Comment: I have no idea as I never used this library, but if you compare `UserQuery` with `UsersQuery` definitions (config), is it exactly the same except for the `resolve`?

Comment: the only difference between the queries that I could see causing an issue is that the `UsersQuery` uses getSelectFields which is in the stacktrace of the failure and I'm not sure how it works and why it would be failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `use App\WorkPreference` import referenced in the below snippet. After adding that it works!

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Types;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;
use App\WorkPreference;

class WorkPreferenceType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name'          => 'WorkPreference',
        'description'   => 'A work preference',
        'model'         => WorkPreference::class,
    ];
```